# Dotnet core 1.0.1 runtime error

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-1.0

I am trying to execute dotnet command from command line it is failed to execute and it showing following error

**api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dss is missing from computer**

Operating system: windows 2012 Rc2 cloud vm.

vc++ 2015 64 and 86

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Missing file should be installed with Windows Update. The problem is that the KB2999226 (Universal CRT) which is part of the Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015 failed to install (try to reinstall them).

Alternatively you can manually install Visual C++ Redistributable.

For Windows 64-bit - http://download.microsoft.com/download/8/5/e/85edb843-93af-4daa-ad1e-c33dfa95b2ea/vc_redist.x64.exe

For Windows 32-bit - http://download.microsoft.com/download/4/5/6/456cf79a-4046-4232-8e6f-7cf3d8075d9a/vc_redist.x86.exe

Answer (score 0):

Finally found root cause, i tried to install .net framework 4.6 in server, installation popped with error message update "2919355" is missing(even though server configured with automatic updates), after installing updates, reinstall vc++ 2015 runtime -> donet core runtime -> works .

Update details available @:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2919355

Note: The updates must be installed in the following order: clearcompressionflag.exe, KB2919355, KB2932046, KB2959977, KB2937592, KB2938439, and KB2934018.

Note: No need to install .net 4.6 in server to run .net core applications, .net 4.6 installation executed to find what update is missing.